# Forbid arrows action in NSCollectionView

Tags: swift, macos, nscollectionview

I'm newbe in macOS development that's why I'm not sure that I've formulated my question correctly. I have multiple NSCollectionView on screen. One of them is main and in other I can select rating, colors etc.. The problem is that when I select color and press right/left arrow I begin moving in `colorCollectionView` not in `mainCollectionView`. Code for handling keys press events is inside of `ViewController` and it obviously not being called. I suspect that issue is connected with `isFirstResponder` property. That's why I've created subclass for my not-main collections:

```
final class NotFirstResponderCollectionView: NSCollectionView {
    override var isFirstResponder: Bool { return false }
}
```

But that didn't resolve problem. Also I've tried to explicitly call `self.becomeFirstResponder` inside of `ViewController` and `.resignFirstResponder` for my not-main collections. That doesn't help me too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you telling the controller to become first responder rather than the collection view you want in focus?

Comment: @Callam Because in controller I have additional key-press logic. I've tried both variants and they didn't work.

Comment: Please add your `ViewController` code

Comment: `isFirstResponder`: "Whether the CollectionView is its window's current firstResponder.  This bindable property is useful for determining appropriate appearance for selected items.". Try `acceptsFirstResponder`: "Whether the responder accepts first responder status.".